# Who first defined functions as binary relations?

Tags: math-history

In modern textbooks on set theory, for example in [Thomas Jech's Set theory, p.11](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662224007), functions are defined as "graphs", i.e. binary relations with the property
$$
(x,y)\in f\ \&\ (x,z)\in f\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=z,
$$
while the definition of binary relation is based on the construction of orded pair as the set 
$$
(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}.
$$
(So this is the standard trick that shows that functions are special cases of sets.)

Can anybody enlighten me who was the author of this idea?

Was that Cantor?

**Edit:** I am not asking why this (Kuratowski's) construction gives a proper definition of ordered pair. My question is who (and when) first defined functions as binary relations (and showed that functions are sets).

**Edit 2:** Ladies and gentlemen, I suppose, before closing this question it would be good to propose an answer.

Comment: [Kuratowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Most_common_implementation_(set_theory))

Comment: @DonThousand when did he suggest this definition?

Comment: Ah. yes, I see, in 1921! Thank you, Don! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ordered Pair Formal Definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286380/ordered-pair-formal-definition)

Comment: @DonThousand , is it possible that Cantor used another trick for showing that functions are sets, before Kuratowski?

Comment: Not sure. I would read through [Cantor's](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485803338) paper on the devil's staircase to see how he defines it.

Comment: @DonThousand Cantor does not discuss this in this paper.

Comment: Relevant : Bertannd Russell. See [*Principles* (1903)](https://books.google.it/books?id=SNWLAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA261) , §254 : "In its most general form, functionality does not differ from relation. […] But this most general idea of a function is of little use in mathematics.
There are two principal ways of particularizing the function: first, we may
confine the relations to be considered to such as are one-one or many-one, i.e. such as give to every referent a unique relatum."

Comment: Into *Principia* (1910-13), Russell & Whitehead developed a mathematical theory of *relations*, where relations are collections of ordered pairs: it was independent of the theory of *classes*, because the book is "pre-Kuratowski" and thus there is no formal reduction of the concept of *pair* to that of sets.

Comment: [Norbert Wiener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener#Harvard_and_World_War_I) "in his Harvard Ph.D. dissertation (June 1913, when he was 18 years: comparison of the work of Ernst Schröder with that of Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell), [discovered] the essential results of which were published as Wiener (1914). […] he was the first to state publicly that ordered pairs can be defined in terms of elementary set theory. Hence relations can be defined by set theory, thus the theory of relations does not require any axioms or primitive notions distinct from those of set theory."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , thank you! So the impression is that Wiener was the first one who stated that functions are sets.

Comment: The first one that discovered/developed the way to represent function as sets.

Comment: We have also to take into account Frege's concept of [Course-of-Values (Werteverlauf)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/#CouExtProMatFou), more or less the modern concept of *graph* of a function.